# Deploying Express server to Firebase issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy my express server to firebase functions. when I try running it with 'firebase serve' command, it runs fine but when I deploy it I cant access any route of my server.

my functions/index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const controller = require('./controller')
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors({ origin: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.json())

app.get('/getGardens', controller.getGardens)
app.post('/getPresentDogsInGarden', controller.getPresentDogsInGarden)

exports.App = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites" : [{"source" : "**", "function" : "App"}]
  }
}
```

my link: ...whatever/App/getGardens

getting in response: 'Error: could not handle the request'

**EDIT:**

solved my problem. everything was ok with the code and initialization.
what I didn't know was that with the free spark plan I cannot use APIs that don't belong to google. I was using mongo in my controller module and it failed to connect. I upgraded to blaze plan and it worked fine.

Comment: What's the exact error in the Firebase functions console?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have something wrong with the project initialization, the .json file should look like this if you're deploying to the functions services :

```
{
  "firestore": {
      "rules": "firestore.rules",
      "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
   }
}
```

And from what i'm seeing you're using the `Hosting` services, you should change it to functions. Right now, what you're trying to do is to deploy you're express code to the hosting service, instead it should be deployed to the functions services.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Medium post that shows how to do this:

https://codeburst.io/express-js-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-86ed26f9144c

Code example:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions")
const express = require("express")

/* Express */
const app1 = express()
app1.get("*", (request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Express on Firebase!")
})

const api1 = functions.https.onRequest(app1)

module.exports = {
  api1
}
```